# Adding a Item to ComboBox and Selecting the same item

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu, combobox

There is a Empty ComboBox to which I will be adding a Item and I want to select the same Item automatically.
Currently I am using the code below and its working.

```
    twComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBoxItem);
            if(twComboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
               twComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

But I feel this method is quite naive. Is there a method to select the added item automatically. I tried searching for the same in google but couldn't find any satisfying answers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to check for a `Count`, because you have an item *guarantyly* added. `Add` will return an index of newly added item. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing the same is

```
twComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBoxItem);
twComboBox1.SelectedItem = ComboBoxItem;
```

OR if you are using [ComboboxItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then you can use

```
twComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBoxItem);
ComboBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see the issue here, the best thing you can do is to remove the if statement containing the count as its not exactly necessary.

```
 twComboBox1.Items.Add(ComboBoxItem);
 twComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Its quick, its easy and it does what you want it to do.